# Goto statement or iteration in HiveQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

How to do iterations in HiveQL? if there is no way to implement a loop, is there a GOTO kind of statement?

I need to perform execution four times with four parameter values, one iteration for each. Is there way to do this without using script?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SparkSQL or any other Hive client in a language that supported procedural express expressions, and have both options. HiveQL alone offers neither.